# Writing sub directories in Hive partitions

Tags: hive, partition, subdirectory

Problem statement

I have files as follows with the schema Event_Time, AD_id

```
file_20170102-May have records with event_time for 20170101,20170102,20170103
file_20170103-May have records with event_time for 20170102,20170103,20170104
```

Here event time is the time when the event occurred and the timestamp on filename is when the events were collected.So the timestamp on the filename and the event_time inside the file are out of sync.

When i write this data to hive i definitely need to write data based on event_time partition because the users are interested in queries based on event_time.

so my out put looks as follow

```
/path/to/output/event_time=20170102/....parquet
/path/to/output/event_time=20170103/....parquet
```

However i need to be able to keep track of file timestamp because some times a file gets reposted and we want to go delete already processed files based on file timestamp.

is there a way i could write this
/path/to/output/event_time=20170101/20170202(file_tiemstamp)

Please note that in the above 20170102(file_timestamp) is a directory and not hive partition.

ALternately can i control the name of the parquet file so when i want to delete a file name its easy to figure out which files to delete

Comment: Any reason you are not using dates ISO format (yyyy-MM-dd)?

Answer (score 0):

### Demo

Files under `/home/dmarkovitz/myfiles`

myfile_1_20161204.csv

```
20161204,1
20161203,2
```

myfile_2_20161205.csv

```
20161203,3
20161204,4
20161205,5
20161203,6
```

myfile_3_20161205.csv

```
20161205,7
20161205,8
20161203,9
```

**hive**

```
create external table myfiles
(
    Event_Time  string
   ,AD_id       int
)
row format delimited
fields terminated by ','
stored as textfile
location 'file:///home/dmarkovitz/myfiles'
;
```

---

```
select  * 
       ,input__file__name
       
from    myfiles 
;
```

---

```
+------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| event_time | ad_id |                  input__file__name                  |
+------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------+
|   20161204 |     1 | file:/home/dmarkovitz/myfiles/myfile_1_20161204.csv |
|   20161203 |     2 | file:/home/dmarkovitz/myfiles/myfile_1_20161204.csv |
|   20161205 |     7 | file:/home/dmarkovitz/myfiles/myfile_3_20161205.csv |
|   20161205 |     8 | file:/home/dmarkovitz/myfiles/myfile_3_20161205.csv |
|   20161203 |     9 | file:/home/dmarkovitz/myfiles/myfile_3_20161205.csv |
|   20161203 |     3 | file:/home/dmarkovitz/myfiles/myfile_2_20161205.csv |
|   20161204 |     4 | file:/home/dmarkovitz/myfiles/myfile_2_20161205.csv |
|   20161205 |     5 | file:/home/dmarkovitz/myfiles/myfile_2_20161205.csv |
|   20161203 |     6 | file:/home/dmarkovitz/myfiles/myfile_2_20161205.csv |
+------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

---

```
create table mytable
(
    AD_id   int
)
partitioned by (file_dt date,Event_Time date)
stored as parquet
;
```

---

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
```

---

```
insert into mytable partition (file_dt,Event_Time)

select  ad_id
       ,from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(split(input__file__name,'[_.]')[2],'yyyyMMdd'),'yyyy-MM-dd')
       ,from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(Event_Time,'yyyyMMdd'),'yyyy-MM-dd')
       
from    myfiles
;
```

---

```
show partitions mytable
;
```

---

```
+------------------------------------------+
|                partition                 |
+------------------------------------------+
| file_dt=2016-12-04/event_time=2016-12-03 |
| file_dt=2016-12-04/event_time=2016-12-04 |
| file_dt=2016-12-05/event_time=2016-12-03 |
| file_dt=2016-12-05/event_time=2016-12-04 |
| file_dt=2016-12-05/event_time=2016-12-05 |
+------------------------------------------+
```

---

```
select  *
       ,input__file__name 
       
from    mytable
;
```

---

```
+-------+------------+------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ad_id |  file_dt   | event_time |                          input__file__name                           |
+-------+------------+------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     2 | 2016-12-04 | 2016-12-03 | file:/mydb/mytable/file_dt=2016-12-04/event_time=2016-12-03/000000_0 |
|     1 | 2016-12-04 | 2016-12-04 | file:/mydb/mytable/file_dt=2016-12-04/event_time=2016-12-04/000000_0 |
|     9 | 2016-12-05 | 2016-12-03 | file:/mydb/mytable/file_dt=2016-12-05/event_time=2016-12-03/000000_0 |
|     3 | 2016-12-05 | 2016-12-03 | file:/mydb/mytable/file_dt=2016-12-05/event_time=2016-12-03/000000_0 |
|     6 | 2016-12-05 | 2016-12-03 | file:/mydb/mytable/file_dt=2016-12-05/event_time=2016-12-03/000000_0 |
|     4 | 2016-12-05 | 2016-12-04 | file:/mydb/mytable/file_dt=2016-12-05/event_time=2016-12-04/000000_0 |
|     7 | 2016-12-05 | 2016-12-05 | file:/mydb/mytable/file_dt=2016-12-05/event_time=2016-12-05/000000_0 |
|     8 | 2016-12-05 | 2016-12-05 | file:/mydb/mytable/file_dt=2016-12-05/event_time=2016-12-05/000000_0 |
|     5 | 2016-12-05 | 2016-12-05 | file:/mydb/mytable/file_dt=2016-12-05/event_time=2016-12-05/000000_0 |
+-------+------------+------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

```
explain dependency
select  *       
from    mytable
where   Event_Time = date '2016-12-04'        
;
```

> {"input_tables":[{"tablename":"local_db@mytable","tabletype":"MANAGED_TABLE"}],"input_partitions":[{"partitionName":"local_db@mytable@file_dt=2016-12-04/event_time=2016-12-04"},{"partitionName":"local_db@mytable@file_dt=2016-12-05/event_time=2016-12-04"}]}

---

**bash**

```
tree mytable
```

---

```
mytable
├── file_dt=2016-12-04
│   ├── event_time=2016-12-03
│   │   └── 000000_0
│   └── event_time=2016-12-04
│       └── 000000_0
└── file_dt=2016-12-05
    ├── event_time=2016-12-03
    │   └── 000000_0
    ├── event_time=2016-12-04
    │   └── 000000_0
    └── event_time=2016-12-05
        └── 000000_0
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer!